# Pushing data directly to Elasticsearch using Rest API call

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is it not possible to injest data directly to Elasticsearch without using any Beat?
My objective is to push data from Jenkins pipeline (groovy) with Rest API call to Elasticsearch. The data I will be visualizing in Kibana dashboard there after.
I don't have access to Jenkins build server hence want to push it to Elasticsearch using Rest API.
Please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you try searching for "Elasticsearch Rest API", for example?

Comment: @MaratC: I could so far explore only a very few  REST API  in Elasticsearch using Postman. But, when I was trying to search and go through documents available - I noticed all the works has been done using either Filebeat or Metricbeat or any other beat to stream data to elasticsearch. As I am doing it first time hence bit confused and consequently urged for the advice. Hope could answer the doubts. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try to install [Logstash plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/logstash/) in jenkins and push Jenkins logs to elasticsearch. Refer to this [Streaming Logdata from jenkins to elasticsearch](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/26/streaming-the-log-data-from-jenkins-pipeline-to-the-elastic-search-and-visualization-in-the-kibana-dashboard/)

Comment: Hi @souravatta,
Thanks for the reply. I actually don't have control to install the Logstash plugin as it is maintained by a central team. But anyway thanks for the suggestion this is also helpful.